# jQuery DataTables Column Show/Hide Toggle using Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a table and I am using jQuery data tables. I wanted to have an option to show/hide a column(s) in my table and I saw this: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html 
In this example, it is done by clicking a link to toggle the show/hide of the column. But what I want to do is to have a modal with column names and checkboxes on each which is when checked or unchecked, upon submit, my table columns should be updated based on the checked/unchecked column names from the modal. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same code. Just instead of anchor tags you'll have check-boxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-vis" data-column="0" value="Name"/>Name
```

And your jQuery event selector will change.

```
 $('.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
} );
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/shweta612/twdfjk87/2/) is a working fiddle for Name column. You can put these checkboxes in your modal window.

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried this if it works in a modal in the same page but I create my modals using partial views so it doesn't work, is there a way I can use checkboxes from a modal partial view to alter data table columns in my main page?

Comment: I tried using modal on the same page and it doesnt work. Any ideas how to make this work with modals?

Comment: Same page modal worked, I just missed the var table declaration for my data tables. For the mean time, I will just use same page modal in that particular page but if you find a way to use partial view modals please post here. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Partial view should work. In order to get the datatable instance in the partial view use `var table = $('#idOfYourTable').dataTable();`. If you are using Jquery datatable version < 1.7 refer to [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2913/how-to-get-the-otable-datatable-object-from-the-table-s-id)